# Is editing a question to use the Spoiler format acceptable?

Tags: discussion, reviewing, spoilers

I have unfortunately on multiple occasions seen answer or questions that i clicked on because i liked the game and ended up seeing a spoiler.

> Whether it be what happened in the story or how to get past a boss.

Is it bad to edit these posts with spoiler markup so that no one else has to see this.

I know that spoiler formatting isn't obvious that it is on the site could this be changed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Of spoilers, plot twists and our mission](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7133/of-spoilers-plot-twists-and-our-mission)

Comment: @Frank: Not really a duplicate. This question is asking if it's acceptable to make an edit *just* to add spoiler markup. That question is about general ideas for how to use the spoiler tag.

Comment: Either way, spoilers don't have any tried and true policy.  My personal opinion is that if the game has been out for a year or more, there's not much point in spoilering it.  At some point, we should stop tap dancing around the fact that this is the internet; you're going to get spoiled.

Comment: So if i decide to play a new release of a series and i like it and i want to go play the original it is fine for people to tell me how it ends

Comment: True spoilers are terrible for any game someone hasn't played it can completely ruin the experience for them

Comment: Dude, it's the *internet*.  You're going to get spoiled.  The only guaranteed method to not being spoiled is to stay off of it.  If you don't want to get spoiled for a certain game here, don't look at its questions.

Comment: @Flaunting I disagree. The effect of spoilers on the enjoyment of stories varies wildly between people; I for one almost *enjoy* spoilers done right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think If you don't put everything in spoiler tags you can go ahead. Basically the most secure ways to tell if something is worth to put into a spoiler tag are:

- If you don't know the part and just got spoiled
- If you already know the part and it is a major plot twist.

Don't use it on stuff that's already 5+ years old and commonly known. Nobody wants a

> Darth Vader is Luke Skywalkers Father

spoiler tag.

Also don't use it on minor things that don't really ruin the experience.

The good thing with edits: First of all you are below 2k Rep currently, this means your posts have to be approved and even above 2k Rep you can still do a rollback. Just always think before you edit.

Comment: +1 purely for the star wars reference

Comment: Also, even if Star Wars were just being released today, if the question was "Who is Luke's father?", putting the answer in spoiler markup would make me rage-punch a birthday clown in the face. Don't browse a question if you don't want the answer!

Answer (score 15):

Here's the golden rule:

> The question and the answers **must** make sense and be complete without using spoiler tags. Even if the spoiler is a major one, it should **not** be protected if that's the very piece of spoiler the question is about.

Feel free to spoiler protect things, but if you don't heed the golden rule, you are doing it wrong. An example is [this suggested edit of yours](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/92606); hopefully now you can understand why it was rejected.

I encourage people to edit posts that go astray of this golden rule.

If you get bit by spoilers due to carelessly browsing through questions — then please be more careful in your browsing :)

Comment: Are you _sure_ you want to spoil the golden rule for yourself? You might be forever spoiled of the fun of figuring it out for yourself!!

Comment: Also, spoiler markup makes people who visit the site on an iPad cry.