# Why was this edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I recently asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359636/where-to-find-rotten-flesh-in-7-days-to-die-alpha-18/), to which I have gotten three excellent answers. One of them contained somewhat of a spoiler, to which one user wrote a comment that spoilers should be put into the appropriate spoiler tags.

I [suggested an edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/280227), which puts the relevant part into spoiler tags and clarifies some phrasing. To my confusion, one person approved this edit, while two rejected them.

The reasons for rejection are unclear to me. One states that it "clearly conflicts with the author's intent", while the other states that "that type of markdown ('<') is reserved for quotations."

I don't understand how putting something that the OP themselves considers a spoiler into a spoiler tag is "going against the author's intent". Furthermore, how is the usage of a spoiler tag (`>!`) "only reserved for quotations"? Is there any rule that states only spoilers that directly correlate to something spoken or written can be put into spoiler tags?

Comment: While I can't speak for the first reviewer (I disagree), I think the second reviewer mistook the spoiler markdown (>!) with blockquote markdown (>)

Comment: @Unionhawk That sounds...unfortunate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of those rejections was mine.
I rejected the edit since - like Unionhawk mentions in the comments - it didn't show up as a spoiler, but as a block quote, and nowhere in the post was mention of a quotation. That's why I added the comment that "that type of markdown ('<') is reserved for quotations" (obviously, it should have been "'>'"...).
Another part of the problem is that I didn't check the comments, which would have elucidated matters.

I beg your pardon for the conflicting signals.

Comment: How should I proceed now? Should I suggest the edit again?

Comment: @MechMK1 Please do!

Comment: I submitted the suggestion again now.

Comment: FWIW, if it shows up the same for you as it does me, it _does_ show as a spoiler and not quote markdown. It's just that the "whole block" was edited and so the text is only faded out and not hidden. If you mouse over you see it gets clearer.

Answer (score 4):

I was one of those who rejected your edit from the review queue. The main reason is: I don't think most of the answer should've been hidden under spoiler markup / formatting. As per the top-voted answer in this meta post: [Is editing a question to use the Spoiler format acceptable?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9809/4797):

> The question and the answers **must** make sense and be complete without using spoiler tags. Even if the spoiler is a major one, it should **not** be protected if that's the very piece of spoiler the question is about.

Aside from that, you've removed this text from the author's original answer. I don't see why removing this text improves the answer:

> Boars as a general rule are none aggro and you may want to avoid hitting them as they are a lot tougher in A18

You also reworded many parts of the answer that didn't really need fixing. e.g. I don't see why "*The following may be a spoiler, but there is one location which contains a high amount of rotten flesh*" is much better than "*May be a bit of a spoiler, if you want a fair bit of rotten flesh fairly fast...*" Most of your edits to the answer are unnecessary rewording, IMHO. Try to avoid unnecessary rewording when you edit. Do not edit most of a post to be hidden inside spoiler markup.

Answer (score 2):

The edit was correctly rejected as "clearly conflits with author's intent". The directions to follow are changed by the edit, the information about the secret area was changed by the edit, the tips about boars were removed by the edit, and the quest that can be used to reset area was removed by the edit.

Edits are only meant to change formatting, syntax, spelling, most everything that is not actual content, but this edit changed the information provided in several ways.

Comment: The directions to follow were changed because the directions given in the edit did not match with the actual location on the in-game map. I know that, because I checked. The information about quests resetting the location is not removed, please see the last paragraph of the edit. The tip about boars being buffed in A18 was removed because it was not related to the question at all. The part about the secret area is within the spoiler. I don't know what made you think I removed all of this information, when I clearly did not.

Comment: @MechMK1 "The direcitons to follow were changed" - yes, that's an issue. As I said, "the quest that can be used to reset area was removed by the edit", not the fact that any quest works. That specific quest was removed, so the content was changed. "The tip about boars being buffed in A18 was removed" - that's an issue. The edit also removes the fact that the secret area is in the house.

Comment: @MechMK1 Changing incorrect information is still changing information. If an answer is wrong, downvote it, don't change the content.

Comment: Discussion was created in a new chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100821/room-for-mechmk1-and-wrigglenite

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the randomness my little post caused. I would have edited it myself however after registering I no longer owned the post so could not edit. Issue resolved now, thanks galacticninja.

Also for the confusion with directions which I thought were correct, I maybe mistakenly assumed most people would have the same thoughts about road directions as myself, i class the first offshoot as a junction (an intersection of roads especially where one terminates) and the second would be a crossroads (a road that crosses a main road) so can see how the information may be taken in a different context, I should have just stated to turn right at the second junction.

Cheers.

Comment: No worries about it. I happened to have my base in the small house, south-west of the pawn shop, so I happened to know the area by heart.